# reusing attribute values on parents

Tags: jquery

I have an image gallery structured like this:

```
<section>
    <div class='centered_image' >
        <img src='images/image1.jpg' alt='first image' />
    </div>
    <div class='centered_image' >
       <img src='images/image2.jpg' alt='second image' />
   </div>
   [etc.]
</section>
```

I need to add an attribute `data-caption` on each div surrounding an image with the value of the `alt` of the image, but I can not change the HTML.

Here's what I've tried:

```
$(function() {
    var caption = $('.centered_image img').attr('alt');
    $('.centered_image').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('data-caption', caption);
    });
});
```

But that uses the `alt` value of the *first* image for each `data-caption`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the corresponding alt attribute using `$(this).find("img").attr("alt")`, use it inside the loop.

```
 $('.centered_image').each(function(){
        caption= $(this).find("img").attr("alt") 
        $(this).attr('data-caption', caption);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate each `centered_image` div and get image to read and set caption.

```
$(function() {
    $('.centered_image').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('data-caption', $(this).find('img').attr('alt'));
    });
});
```

Alternatively you can also use

```
$(function() {
    $('.centered_image').attr('data-caption', function(){
        return $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
    });
});
```